# Infopath Sharepoint forms

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I have been given a simple task of creating a sharepoint form, collect few information, Make and API call, do some calculation using response from API and the original input and show results on the page.

I don’t have much experience in working with sharepoint or infopath. I have been told that infopath is the way to achieve this

Can someone suggest what’s the best way to achieve this ?
Can we use JS in infopath ? Or is it only c# ?

FYI:- power apps is not an option due to legacy platforms

Comment: Please make your requirements more exact. Can you describe your business logic ? I cannot understand where you need API calls ? Is it must be on list item form or in some page ? My first thoughts - don't use InfoPath for this tasks... =) Use JS, it can perform many things. It depends on your business logic.

Comment: The requirement is simple if we put sharepoint out of the equation then all I need to do is :

1. Create a webpage and collect some data from user
2. Using that data make an API Call 
3. Based on the response from API call display the results back to user

The only problem that I face is that I have never worked on sharepoint and this page has to be implemented on sharepoint 

Googling on how to achieve this gives mixed results like inforpath, powerapps and what not.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has out-of-box features to implement your logic to collect data from user. It is out-of-box list and its list items. On list item creating you have out-of-box form with fields. No InfoPath required. You can add on this form some logic to implement your API calls and displaying its result. I think If I correctly understood then you can do it without any additional tools. You will need just to write code for API calls. SharePoint has also out-of-box list view. Here you can see all data collected from users.
InfoPath required if you need difficult form logic. Like I want choose value here and another value will be calculated on this value and set to another field and additionally will be formatted.